# styled-component import results in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm just getting into `styled-components` and am having a little bit of an issue. I'm trying to extend a `button` through different files and for some reason it imports as `undefined`

This error initially appeared with a `NavLink` component which led to believe it might be a react issue but it also happens with a ``` styled.a``; ``` so I don't think that's it.

StyledComponents.jsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Button = styled.a`
  // general styling
`;
```

App.jsx

```
import { Button } from './StyledComponents/StyledComponents';

console.log(Button); // this works fine

export const MainButton = styled(Button)`
  // a little color and other styles
`;
```

Banner.jsx

```
import { MainButton } from '../App';

console.log(MainButton); // returns undefined

// if I omit the console logging above, this gives error of undefined
const _MainButton = styled(MainButton)`
  // specific styles for this component
`;
```

I am not really sure what is going on. I am also not sure if this is the correct way to layer these styled components. If someone could share some insight, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is `styled` even a function? Because you're calling it like it returns a function that you then call with some styles.

Comment: It is, if you want to pass it other components, and not html elements, where you do `styled.div` eg

Comment: Notice how in `App.jsx` the `Button` and `MainButton` work fine. When they are imported in `Banner.jsx` however, it breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So okay, this export convolution is the problem. You're importing a button from `StyledComponents.jsx` into `App.jsx`, which you then export as `MainButton`, and then import again into `Banner.jsx`, which is rendered in the `LandingPage`, which is rendered in the `App.jsx`. Whew. I literally solved this by just moving the `MainButton` definition and export into another file. I'm not sure why, but that's what it was. Keeping styled components in a dedicated files is a good idea! For example, moving the `MainButton` to a different file:

**/StyledComponents/StyledComponents.jsx**

```
export const MainButton = styled(Button)`
    //styles go here
`;
```

And then changing the import:

**Banner.jsx**

```
import { MainButton } from '../StyledComponents/StyledComponents';
```

works just fine!

In general, though, if you want to layer stuff with styled-components, I like to keep it in a single file. You don't have to export them all if you don't need all, but you also can:

```
const TitleBase = styled.h1`
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
`;

export const GreenTitle = styled(Title)`
  color: green;
`;

export const RedTitle = styled(Title)`
  color:red;
`;
```

Just make sure they are in order. You can't define `Title` after `RedTitle` eg.

A small tip: it's also okay to use `.js` extension instead of `.jsx`, but you're free to do whatever you want!

Comment: The `'../App';` seems to be correct. I have an `App.jsx` file in the parent directory of `Banner.jsx`'s directory which has all of the global components for this project. That's why it's strange to me.

Comment: This is really strange. If I use `<MainButton />` directly in `Banner.jsx` it works. If I import it and try to style it through `_MainButton` it gives me an error of undefined. What's even more weird is if I do `console.log(MainButton)` it will log undefined but  `<MainButton />` will show up properly.

Comment: The only reason the code you posted would return undefined is if the import was wrong. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/8lvnoy2jz0

Comment: Could you post entire `Banner.jsx` file somewhere? now it sounds like a race condition...

Comment: Here's the file and the repo on GitHub. If you absolutely need me to, I can also give it to you in codesandbox.  GitHub was just faster. https://github.com/dariuscosden/_cosdenio/blob/master/static/react/LandingPage/Banner.jsx

Comment: How do you run the dev env on this one?

Comment: command line `export FLASK_ENV=development`, also `export FLASK_APP=server`, and then `flask run`

Comment: Figured it out, no idea how to explain this though.. let me try

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Updated the answer. Usually, when I need a simple styled components once, I'll make it in the file where I need it. However, having `styled/buttons.js` with just the buttons styled components, and export as you need them, may not be a bad idea!

Comment: You said you moved the MainButton definition and export in another file. Where did you move it may I ask? So I can replicate it on my side.

Comment: There you go, that should do it

Comment: I got it to work as well. Took your advice and created a separate `Buttons.jsx` (personal preference to use .jsx instead .js) and imported it from there. I am also not sure what caused it but I will look into it and try to understand. I really like your idea of having a separate `Buttons.jsx` file. I'm all for organizing stuff and keeping it efficient! Thanks a TON for your help man. I'll of course go ahead and mark this as accepted answer!

Comment: Yeah, my Atom doesn't register jsx at all lol, it's just white! To be honest, I never tried to import anything from a parent component like that, but my rule of thumb is: if I need the same styled component in more than one place, even just to extend it, it goes into its' own file, a file that houses only styled components! Anytime man, good luck